# Bamboo job Fails to execute VBScript with Connection string to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: vbscript, bamboo

I have a Bamboo Plan to execute a VB script which connects to Microsoft SQL Server and performs some operation on SQL server with a return value, Script works fine when i execute manually but fails when i trigger the script from Bamboo Job

the VBScript lies on Window machine and so had configured a remote agent to execute this script Normal VBS scripts works fine except the VBscript with the connection string to DBfails with error message as "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\USERNAME$"

VB Script

```
Option Explicit

Dim strFile, objFSO, objFile, strConnect, adoSQLConnection, adoSQLRecordset
Dim adoSQLCommand, arrValues, pat, line,cr, var
Dim JobID, Jquery, SQLexecute, SQLTextFile, qfile       

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

' Specify csv file.

strFile = "D:\MIS_Scripts\DEV_MIS_Scripts\CSV\Domain.csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)

' Connection string for SQL database.
strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=SQLAU301MEL0435.globaltest.anz.com\TESTAUTOMATION;Initial Catalog=Visualisation;Integrated Security=SSPI"

' Connect to SQL Server database.
Set adoSQLConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoSQLConnection.ConnectionString = strConnect
adoSQLConnection.Open

' Create Recordset object for SQL Server database.
Set adoSQLRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set adoSQLRecordset.ActiveConnection = adoSQLConnection

Jquery = "select max(JobID) from dbo.Job_Test"
adoSQLRecordset.open Jquery, strConnect
JobID = adoSQLRecordset(0).value
adoSQLRecordset.close

WScript.echo JobID

enter code here

objFile.Close

adoSQLConnection.Close
```

Manual Execution steps on cmd : cscript filname.vbs

is there any steps i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string appears to be using integrated security meaning the SQL Server login will use the account running the script. So, does is the account running the agent setup for the right access to SQL Server?

You can use a username/password and use a plan variables that you send along to the VB Script...